# ImageView bad size CardView in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-glide, cardview

I have a problem with my **ImageView** inside a **CardView** in a **RecyclerView**.

I load my Image with **Glide**, but, the first time y open the Application, the **ImageView** inside a **CardView** inside a **Recyclerview** show wrong *width and height*, but, If I go to other Activity and come back again to the *recyclerView*, I will see the Image with the correct size.

[Bad size, Selected in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnfQf.jpg)

[Good size after come from other activty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmGj4.jpg)

As you can see, the **Green color should not be seen**.

Here you can see the Vegetable.xml:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/cardViewVegetables"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/corner_radius_cardview"
card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_cardview"
card_view:cardMaxElevation="@dimen/elevation_cardview"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/md_green_900">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutVegetable1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_black_1000">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVegetable1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            />
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/nameVegetable1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteGrayVegetable"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutVegetable2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVegetable2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
        <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
            android:id="@+id/nameVegetable2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/whiteGrayVegetable"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLines="2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And here the code from recyclerview:

```
public class vegetableRVA extends RecyclerView.Adapter<vegetableRVA.VegetableViewHolder>{

private Context context;
private List<vegetable> Vegetables;

class VegetableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private AutofitTextView vegetableName1;
    private AutofitTextView vegetableName2;
    private ImageView vegetablePhoto1;
    private ImageView vegetablePhoto2;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutVegetable1;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayoutVegetable2;
        VegetableViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            vegetableName1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameVegetable1);
            vegetableName2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameVegetable2);
            vegetableName1.setTextSize((float)context.getResources()
                          .getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/25);
            vegetableName1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            vegetableName2.setTextSize((float)context.getResources()
                          .getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/25);
            vegetableName2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            vegetablePhoto1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVegetable1);
            vegetablePhoto2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageVegetable2);

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VegetableViewHolder vegetableViewHolder, int position) {
      int widthDP = (int) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 2;
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName1.setMaxWidth(widthDP);
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName1.setSizeToFit();
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName1.setMaxTextSize((int) widthDP/12);
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName2.setMaxWidth(widthDP);
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName2.setSizeToFit();
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetableName2.setMaxTextSize((int) widthDP/12);
      
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto1.setImageDrawable(null);
      vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto2.setImageDrawable(null);
      if (context != null) {
           Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(Vegetables.get(position).getImageVegetableDisyuntive().get(0))
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .override(widthDP+50,heightDP+50 )
                .into(vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto1);
           Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(Vegetables.get(position).getImageVegetableDisyuntive().get(1))
                .dontAnimate()
                .centerCrop()
                .override(widthDP+50, heightDP+50)
                .into(vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto2);
       }
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widthDP,heightDP);
       vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto1.setLayoutParams(parms);
       vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto2.setLayoutParams(parms);
       vegetableViewHolder.vegetablePhoto1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
  }
```

I don't know why the size of the Image in the CardView has bad size the first time I open de app but, after open other activity, the size is OK.

Comment: Both `RelativeLayout`s have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, but all its' children have `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. That probably leads to an impossible state, which happens to be correct in some occasions.

Comment: And, what will be the best state?, `RelativeLayout`  with `android:layout_with="match_parent"` and all childens with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` ?

Comment: I have changed all `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `wrap_content` but it looks the same.